# DHCP not updating DNS

Tags: dns, dhcp, dynamic-dns, rhel-5, dhcp-server

RHEL5.6, bind-9.3.6, and dhcp-3.0.5

So, after I [fixed my problem](https://superuser.com/questions/506631/dhcpd-not-processing-broadcast-dhcpdiscover) with getting DHCP to parse the MAC addresses for these virtual machines, now I need to figure out how to get it to update DNS when one of those virtual hosts is up and active.

I've [configured bind for dDNS](http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/dynamic-dns-with-dhcp/) and used `nsupdate` to verify named will accept dynamic updates.

I've configured DHCP to update its static leases and its pool. However, neither the `dhcpd.log` nor the `named.log` show any attempts at updating the DNS tables. On the other hand, the `nsupdate` tests show up in the `named.log` just fine.

So, I can verify that `named` will receive and accept updates, but I can't verify `dhcpd` is trying to send them.

The questions:

- What might I have missed in my `dhcpd.conf` (or in `/etc/sysconfig/dhcpd`)?
- Has anyone used `log{}` functionality in `dhcpd.conf` to confirm/refute dDNS updates?

Thanks!

Here are some `dhcpd.conf` snips:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
update-static-leases on;

key dhcpupdate
{
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret <KEY>;
}

zone 22.YYY.XXX.in-addr.arpa
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

zone 23.YYY.XXX.in-addr.arpa
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

zone 24.YYY.XXX.in-addr.arpa
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

zone example.com
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

zone sub1.example.com
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

zone sub2.example.com
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

zone sub3.example.com
{
  primary XXX.YYY.22.168;
  key dhcpupdate;
}

subnet XXX.YYY.24.0 netmask 255.255.254.0
{
  group
  {
    ddns-hostname "example.com";

    host <hostfqdn> { hardware ethernet <MAC>; fixed address <hostfqdn>;}
    ...
  }

  group
  {
    ddns-hostname "sub1.example.com";

    host <hostfqdn> { hardware ethernet <MAC>; fixed address <hostfqdn>;}
    ...
  }

  group
  {
    ddns-hostname "sub2.example.com";

    host <hostfqdn> { hardware ethernet <MAC>; fixed address <hostfqdn>;}
    ...
  }

  group
  {
    ddns-hostname "sub3.example.com";

    host <hostfqdn> { hardware ethernet <MAC>; fixed address <hostfqdn>;}
    ...
  }
}
subnet XXX.YYY.24.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
{
  option routers XXX.YYY.24.254;
  option domain-name-servers XXX.YYY.22.168, XXX.YYY.22.169;
  option ntp-servers XXX.YYY.22.168,XXX.YYY.22.169;
  default-lease-time 86400; # 1 day
  max-lease-time 604800;    # 7 days
  use-host-decl-names on;
  allow unknown-clients;

  option domain-name "example.com sub1.example.com sub2.example.com sub3.example.com";
  ddns-domainname "example.com";
  next-server XXX.YYY.22.159;
  filename "pxelinux.0";

  pool
  {
    allow members of "virtual-hosts";
    one-lease-per-client true;
    ping-check true;
    range XXX.YYY.24.11 XXX.YYY.24.60;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, the piece I was missing is on the client side. In RHEL5, I need to [set DHCP_HOSTNAME to the host's short name](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/Deployment_Guide/index.html#s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0) for the dhclient to pass to the `dhcpd` daemon.

(Before I saw that text that specifies the short name, I tried with the FQDN. Now, I'll have to restart the DNS server to delete an accidental `host.1.example.com.1.example.com`, due to my `dhcpd` daemon not truncating the domain portion...)

Answer (score 0):

On all the systems I have worked with, it has been the client's responsibility to update DNS.  Most DHCP clients have a way to specify which DNS to notify.

If you are using `bind`, the default configurations I have worked with have had dynamic updates disabled.

For this kind of setup, I use `dnsmasq` to provide the DHCP and DNS services.  It will update its DNS responses using the name provided in the DHCP request.

Even simpler is to use fixed IP addresses for the virtual machines.  These can be added to DNS and will always be available.  Most DHCP servers, including `dnsmasq` can provide fixed IP addresses based on the MAC address.

Comment: I may have to go with `dnsmasq`. The link I shared above and [this one](http://markembling.info/2011/10/dhcp-and-dynamic-dns) both suggest it should be possible to do from the server side.

Comment: The vast majority of my entries are `fixed-address` hosts. But, I need a pool for a set of virtual hosts that are being configured. The vhosts get static hostnames for their app. config files, but my DHCP/DNS provides the IP addresses as the vhosts are launched or retired. The weird thing is that I now see entries where DHCP has tried to update a couple of my `fixed-address` hosts. I'm looking at why those two are different...

Comment: In my continued reading, I just read through the section titled "The Interim DNS Update Scheme" in the [dhcpd.conf(5)](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/dhcpd.conf.5.php) man page. The paragraphs discussing `allow client-update;` vs. `ignore client-update;` describe exactly what I'm trying to do: DHCP takes a client-provided hostname and a pool IP address, and updates DNS dynamically.

Comment: Its been many years since I used a standalone DHCP server.  It is good to see that they are working on getting it integrated with DNS.